# Projecting Lambert WGS 84 using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, lambert-conformal-conic

I am currently preparing raster layers in QGIS to be fed into MaxEnt to run a species distribution model.

I downloaded climatic variables in ascii format from I downloaded from Adaptwest (https://adaptwest.databasin.org/pages/adaptwest-climatena) with the following parameters:

```
Projection    LAMBERT
Datum         WGS84
Spheroid      WGS84
Units         METERS
Zunits        NO
Xshift        0.0
Yshift        0.0

Parameters
49  0  0.0 /* 1st standard parallel
77  0  0.0 /* 2nd standard parallel
-95  0  0.0 /* central meridian
0  0  0.0 /* latitude of projection's origin
0.0 /* false easting (meters)
0.0 /* false northing (meters)
```

I will need to crop this raster with states boundaries shape files in CSR WSG 84 but I am unable to successfully re-project the ASCII files so that they overlap with the states shape files.

I tried a solution posted in this Q&A site in which I created a CSR using the above parameters:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=77 +lat_0= 0 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

but I am still unable to re-project. I get no error messages but the outcome is wrong.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does your asc file have a prj file or aux file with the projection defined? Are you trying to crop using gdal_warp with -cutline? If not how are you trying to crop your raster.. details are important here.

Comment: Try +proj=lcc +lat_1=49.00 +lat_2=77.00 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-95 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs as your Proj.4 string... What spatial reference are you trying to convert to?

Comment: Hello Michael! Thanks for your response. I think there was a glitch in QGIS because I am now able to overlay my states shape files with the rasters by setting up the CSR to the one I created. However, when re-projecting: Raster>Projection>Warp to WGS 84 pseudo mercator, the raster values changed. Trying to figure out this part out now, but I guess I will need to post a different question for this.

Comment: Are you trying to warp and clip at the same time? Try warping to EPSG:3857 (https://epsg.io/3857) first, transform your boundaries too from (I assume) EPSG:4326 (WGS84 Geographic) then warp to the same using cutline.. it might be having difficulty transforming the raster and the cutline at the same time.

Comment: I am trying to warp the layers first to make sure I am getting the same original values as this could really changed the outcome of my model. I read that the differences maybe due to the re-sampling method selected. I am unfortunately getting different values for each of the re-sampling methods, nothing near to the original values.

Comment: If the values are critical then work in the CRS of the original raster, any resampling will change the values slightly. The next best is using resampling method Near which will use the value of the nearest matching pixel.

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael! I did as you said and I re-project the layer after cropping to minimize the error. The outcome rasters values seems to vary within a reasonable range.